# Fetch multiple posts from JSON Placeholder with one API call

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

So, my question is, can you fetch multiple posts from JSON Placeholder API, but call fetch once, and fetch 12 posts for example. This is what I did so far, but when I go into network in inspect element, I get 12 API calls, and I want it to be 1 if it is possible

```js
const fetchPosts = (id) => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + id)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
      var result = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
      result.innerHTML += "<div class=\"posts\">" + json.title + "</div>";
    });
};
for(let i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    fetchPosts(i);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Does the backend support it?

Comment: @jabaa What do you mean?

Comment: Does the backend support to send a response with multiple posts for a single request? Currently, you're sending multiple requests. I don't understand why you would expect only one request in your network monitor. You can't group or bundle requests and handle them on the other side as if it were multiple requests without the backend supporting it. You could consider using GraphQL instead of REST.

Comment: @jabaa Well, i have the code with multiple requests, but our mentors asked us if we can do it with 1 request, and I dont seem to know how to do that, thats why im asking if it is even possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. You have to send one request and the backend sends a response containing multiple posts. But someone has to program it.

Comment: @jabaa Okay, so do i put the fetch in a variable, how do i do that, because i'm trying to do it with a for loop, as you can see in my code.

Comment: If you want to send one request, you have to call `fetch` only once. The browser will send one request per call of `fetch`.

Comment: @jabaa yes, but how do i itterate through that request then, i want to get 12 posts form the API, and if i call it once, i just get one.

Comment: Now, we're back at my first comment. Does the backend support this? What's the API of the backend? Does the backend support requests for multiple posts? A REST API should support requests for all posts. Is this a solution? Many APIs support requests with pagination.

Comment: @jabaa im sorry, but i really dont know, on the website, there is only a code how to implement it, and thats all. I dont see anything on their [website](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/)

Comment: _"A REST API should support requests for all posts. Is this a solution?"_

Comment: _"can you fetch multiple posts from JSON Placeholder API"_ You can fetch all posts or one post. You can use a filter to select multiple posts.

Comment: @jabaa Yes, i can fetch all the posts with code that i just did, but then i make 100 fetch requests for 100 posts.

Comment: You really should read the full (very short) documentation and not stop at the first code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API supports a filter. You can pass a list of IDs and other properties, e.g.:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=0&id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4&id=5&id=6&id=7&id=8&id=9&id=10&id=11')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

It sends one request and returns a response containing an array of posts:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati",
    "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "nesciunt quas odio",
    "body": "repudiandae veniam quaerat sunt sed\nalias aut fugiat sit autem sed est\nvoluptatem omnis possimus esse voluptatibus quis\nest aut tenetur dolor neque"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "dolorem eum magni eos aperiam quia",
    "body": "ut aspernatur corporis harum nihil quis provident sequi\nmollitia nobis aliquid molestiae\nperspiciatis et ea nemo ab reprehenderit accusantium quas\nvoluptate dolores velit et doloremque molestiae"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "title": "magnam facilis autem",
    "body": "dolore placeat quibusdam ea quo vitae\nmagni quis enim qui quis quo nemo aut saepe\nquidem repellat excepturi ut quia\nsunt ut sequi eos ea sed quas"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "title": "dolorem dolore est ipsam",
    "body": "dignissimos aperiam dolorem qui eum\nfacilis quibusdam animi sint suscipit qui sint possimus cum\nquaerat magni maiores excepturi\nipsam ut commodi dolor voluptatum modi aut vitae"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 9,
    "title": "nesciunt iure omnis dolorem tempora et accusantium",
    "body": "consectetur animi nesciunt iure dolore\nenim quia ad\nveniam autem ut quam aut nobis\net est aut quod aut provident voluptas autem voluptas"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 10,
    "title": "optio molestias id quia eum",
    "body": "quo et expedita modi cum officia vel magni\ndoloribus qui repudiandae\nvero nisi sit\nquos veniam quod sed accusamus veritatis error"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 11,
    "title": "et ea vero quia laudantium autem",
    "body": "delectus reiciendis molestiae occaecati non minima eveniet qui voluptatibus\naccusamus in eum beatae sit\nvel qui neque voluptates ut commodi qui incidunt\nut animi commodi"
  }
]
```

Example:

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=0&id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4&id=5&id=6&id=7&id=8&id=9&id=10&id=11")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    const html = data.reduce((acc, el) => acc + "<div class=\"posts\">" + el.title + "</div>", '');
    const result = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
    result.innerHTML = html;
  });
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

JSONPlaceholder is based on [JSON Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) and supports pagination. You can achieve the same result with

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=0&_limit=12')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Comment: @JovanJovanovic Programming is >80% reading and <20% coding. If you don't like reading documentation, you'll have a hard time in programming. I just copied some snippets from documentations and modified them according to your code.